# get the title of post from specific category without loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying this code :

```
<ul>
<?php 
$casino_news = new WP_Query('category_name=casino_games'); 
while($casino_news ->have_posts()) :
 $casino_news ->the_post(); 
?>
<li>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

and it works perfectly for me. But if I am trying to search that the post is not exists, it will show nothing on that widget.

what can I prevent from this situation?

Comment: well what do you want to happen if no posts are found?

Comment: For me, I want only the title of all that posts by category id

Comment: use `wp_reset_query();` to reset your wp_query just after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope It will work , let me know if you face any problem with this.

```
<ul>
<?php 
$casino_news = new WP_Query('category_name=casino_games'); 
while($casino_news->have_posts()) :
 if($casino_news->get_the_post() == '' ){
     $casino_news->the_title(); 
 }else{
     $casino_news->the_post(); 
 } 
?>
<li>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have put this in my widget and the whole website stop working unless I remove this.

Comment: @APov  I have made a slight change can you try and let me know .